# Some sort of meta data for Dictionary

Tags: vba

I have set up a dictionary with a long list of keys and associated items. The user enters a string of keywords via an input box and vba splits each word into an array, finds the key and adds the item to an output string. For example:

User types in "Dinner Applebee's Restaurant", the code splits the string into three words, then makes a number code where each word is represented by a two-digit number "10 08 70" (*spaces added to emphasize number schema*).

Here's the problem, "Applebee's Restaurant" flows a little better in English than "Restaurant Applebee's" so the user would most likely type the words in that order but the number should really reflect "Restaurant Applebee's." Like it should be category then place instead of place then category. The number code should actually be "10 70 08."

Is there a way to group dictionary definitions without making a separate dictionary? Or evaluate each word and sort them into a particular order? As in the first two digits will always be greater than 10, the second two digits  will also be greater than 10 or will be 00. The third two digits will always be less than 10. So as long as I know what word has less than 10, that number can be last.

It would be easy enough to just type the words in the correct order, but I fear the lay person hardly ever takes the easy route and there is a number of people who will use this, each at their own questionable level of computer-literacy.

An example of code was requested so here it is:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim InStr As String   ' Input string
Dim Split() As String ' Array to hold words
Dim SegNum As String  ' Output string
Dim I As Integer

' Adding searchable items to dictionary
' First two digits
dict.Add Key:="Dinner", Item:=10
dict.Add Key:="Lunch", Item:=15
dict.Add Key:="Breakfast", Item:=20
dict.Add Key:="Snack", Item:=50

' Second two digits
dict.Add Key:="Restaurant", Item:=70
dict.Add Key:="Home Cooked", Item:=80

' Third two digits
dict.Add Key:="Home", Item:=Format(0, "00)
dict.Add Key:="McDonald's", Item:=Format(1, "00")
dict.Add Key:="Burger King", Item:=Format(2,"00")
dict.Add Key:="Wendy's", Item:=Format(3, "00")
..
dict.Add Key:="Applebee's", Item:=Format(8, "00")

SplitStr = Split(InputBox("Please use some keywords to detail what you ate"), " ")

For I = LBound(SplitStr) To UBound(SplitStr)
     SegNum = SegNum & dict(SplitStr(I))
Next
MsgBox SegNum
```

Comment: I'll mention that the there is specific number of keywords that would be used and for the most part every possible word that would be used has been defined. This is just a matter of making sure that words are arranged in the correct order so that the number code will be in the correct order.

Comment: Do you have code you can show us?

Comment: are your number codes fixed or can they be altered? If you can alter the number codes, you could organize them so that sorting the resulting numbers high-low would result in the appropriate code.

Comment: I just edited the question to explain how the code works. They can't be altered. For all intents and purposes 10 always means Dinner in the first two-digits. 10 in the second two-digits means something else entirely.

Comment: As for showing code @Ryan, I don't really have any that I can show. I'm not actually talking about restaurants and meals. I'm using them as a place holder. I'll try to type out an example without giving away company secrets :)

Comment: Unrelated, but `Dim whatever As New Something` is usually a bad idea. Unless you know about the implications of an auto-instantiated object.

Comment: Care to elaborate @Mat'sMug? This is my first time using Dictionary so I just yanked the code from some forum and made it my own.

Comment: You can't `Set foo = Nothing` if `foo` was declared `As New`. Well you can, but then `Debug.Print foo Is Nothing` will print `False`. Weird bugs ensue.

Comment: Use an array for your dictionary values: e.g. `dict.Add Key:="Dinner", Item:=Array(10, 1)` where the second entry is the "sort order" for the code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that sounds perfect. However, how do I call the second value? Some kind of if statement where "dict.Item(1) = i (dependent on the iteration in the for loop)?

Comment: `dict("dinner")(1)` (eg) should do it, but you'll need to capture the items and then sort the codes by the second array element.  And figure out what to do if there are >1 of any "sort order" item.  All in all it would likely be easier to just use 3 different dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach.  You'd need to add in checks for two entries from the same category though.

And you have "home cooked" as a value - that will get broken up by `Split()`

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim InStr As String   ' Input string
    Dim SplitStr() As String ' Array to hold words
    Dim SegNum As String  ' Output string
    Dim I As Long, srt As Long, wd

    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

    srt = 1
    dict.Add Key:="Dinner", Item:=Array(10, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="Lunch", Item:=Array(15, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="Breakfast", Item:=Array(20, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="Snack", Item:=Array(50, srt)

    ' Second two digits
    srt = 2
    dict.Add Key:="Restaurant", Item:=Array(70, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="HomeCooked", Item:=Array(80, srt)

    ' Third two digits
    srt = 3
    dict.Add Key:="Home", Item:=Array(0, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="McDonald's", Item:=Array(1, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="Burger King", Item:=Array(2, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="Wendy's", Item:=Array(3, srt)
    dict.Add Key:="Applebee's", Item:=Array(8, srt)

    SegNum = String(6, " ")

    SplitStr = Split("dinner home homecooked")
    'SplitStr = Split(InputBox("Please use some keywords to detail what you ate"), " ")

    For I = LBound(SplitStr) To UBound(SplitStr)
         wd = Trim(SplitStr(I))
         If dict.Exists(wd) Then
            srt = dict(wd)(1)
            Mid(SegNum, 1 + ((srt - 1) * 2), 2) = Format(dict(wd)(0), "00")
         End If
    Next

    MsgBox SegNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, that I do. That was something I noticed as I was writing the keys, but figured I'd burn that bridge when I get to it. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Holy cow that worked! Not that I doubted it, I just didn't understand what some of the lines were doing. Can you explain the Mid function? I get what Mid does in general, it's the math that's throwing me.

Comment: There are two slots per code (starting at positions 1,3,5) so that's a bit of math to find the starting position given the sort order.  You could just as easily use 1,3,5 in place of 1,2,3 in the dictionary and save that calculation...

Comment: It seems so obvious now. Thanks for that. Now I just have to add the *4th* set of numbers, but that's doable with a select case since it's pretty dependent the 2nd set of numbers.

As an aside, do you have any tips on the "Home Cooked" issue? I've added 2 keys, one without a space and one with. It's very likely that the user will have a space. I could just look for Home and ignore Cooked? I have multiple "[x] Cooked" keys but Home is a unique word.

Comment: Using any keys with spaces will be a problem.  This approach seems very susceptible to typos etc - it would be easier (for the user) to give them a userform with the items listed and let them pick from that.

Comment: I think I found a workaround for that. Since every item in the dictionary is pretty unique I can just take out the first letter of the word and the last two characters of the second word and join them with an asterisk so that it doesn't matter what the user typed as long as the user didn't mess up three characters (which is a lot less likely than whole words at a time). It'll be an interesting day of work tomorrow. Thanks for the help!